# Laravel7 CORS : blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, cors, magento2

**Use case: VueJS/Laravel app has inventory. Calling Magento2 using SOAP API to update Qty from VueJS/Laravel.**

**Error as shared below**:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://xx.yyy.abc.123/rest/V1/integration/admin/token?username=admin&password=xxxxx'
>   from origin 'http://192.168.0.x' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Note: I am a beginner in this domain. I might be asking stupid questions. Please bear with me and requesting help here.

Tools/Apps used:

1. Laravel Framework 7.9.2 /Running on http://192.168.0.x
2. VueJS /Running on http://192.168.0.x
3. Magento2 /Running on http://xx.yyy.abc.123
4. Postman (Tool used to test SOAP API)

Debugging efforts:

1. URL http://xx.yyy.abc.123/rest/V1/integration/admin/token?username=admin&password=xxxxx
2. Tried from postman: It works, Apended token into postmane and got the response.
3. Making AXIOS call from VueJS/Laravel application to Magento2:**(Failed)**

```
Origin: http://192.168.0.x 
Magento2: http://xx.yyy.abc.123
```

```
  axios.post("http://xx.yyy.abc.123/rest/V1/integration/admin/token?username=admin&password=xxxxx",
  {

  })
  .then((response) =>
  {
        console.log("response.data",response.data);
        this.apiResponse = response.data;
        //this.getproduct();
  })
  .catch(error =>
  {
       alert('ERROR GETCATEGORY!!!! No Data found');
       console.log(error.response);
  });
```

4. Checked for 2 days now about CORS error and found that this is enabled by default in Laravel 7. Not sure why I am seeing this error even after using Laravel 7. There are very few answers or solutions specific to VueJS with Laravel 7.

Question:

1. What does this error means. I thought it is just calling from webpage1 to webpage2, it does not seem to work.
2. Do I need to make any changes on my VueJS/Laravel application. Am I missing anything further.

Please do let me know if you need any more information to help me in this regards.
Thanks for your help.
Regards,

Comment: CORS needs to be enabled in the Magento2 app not in the Laravel app

Comment: Thank you.. one clarification is does this have any issues on security part as Magento2 will have payment gateway running or any issues or threats on security part.

Comment: Blocking CORS requests is done to provide security for your users, so if you do unblock them you need to ensure that the requests coming in are indeed from Laravel somehow. So it's `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` explicitly has the allowed origins rather than using `*`

Comment: So it will be Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://192.168.0.x .. So basically need to add Origin ip so that others dont have access to it. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong. Thank you again.

Comment: What you don't want is one of your users going to site `evil.com` and that site sending a CORS request on the user's behalf to buy items

Answer (score 0):

I had got the same CORS error while working on a Vue.js project. I finally solved this issue just today in the morning.  You can resolve this either by building a proxy server or another way would be to disable the security settings of your browser (eg, CHROME) for accessing cross origin apis. Both these solutions had worked for me. The later solution is the easiest solutoion and does not require any mock server or a proxy server to be build. Both these solutions can be resolved at the front end.

You can disable your browser (CHROME) security settings for accessing apis out of the origin by typing the below command on the terminal:

/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_dev_session" --disable-web-security

After running the above command on your terminal, a new chrome window with security settings disabled will open up. Now, run your program (npm run serve / npm run dev) again and this time you will not get any CORS error and would be able to GET request using axios.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you for time taken to respond. Appreciate that. Can you please confirm on which terminal (Win or ubuntu) or just can we set from chrome settings also?... will try and share you the update once I have more details on this. Thanks.

Comment: I used mac terminal. I did this using command line only. I guess this command would work on ubuntu terminal and via windows cmd as well. Give it a try.

Comment: Thank you so much. You made my day. It worked for me.   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application>chrome.exe --disable-web-security --disable-gpu --user-data-dir=~/ChromeTemp`